# AVCapture and zooming of previewLayer in Swift

Tags: swift3, avfoundation, avcapture, xcode8

I have a camera app which allows the user to both take pictures and record video. The iPhone is attached to a medical otoscope using an adapter, so the video that is captured is very small (about the size of a dime). I need to be able to zoom the video to fill the screen, but have not been able to figure out how to do so.

I found [this answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373243/zooming-while-capturing-video-using-avcapture-in-ios#) that uses ObjC but have not had success in translating it to Swift. I am very close but am getting stuck. Here is my code for handling a UIPinchGestureRecgoznier:

```
    @IBAction func handlePinchGesture(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    var initialVideoZoomFactor: CGFloat = 0.0

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began) {
        initialVideoZoomFactor = (captureDevice?.videoZoomFactor)!
    } else {
        let scale: CGFloat = min(max(1, initialVideoZoomFactor * sender.scale), 4)

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.01)
        previewLayer?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        CATransaction.commit()

        if ((captureDevice?.lockForConfiguration()) != nil) {
            captureDevice?.videoZoomFactor = scale
            captureDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
        }

    }
}
```

This line...

```
previewLayer?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
```

... gives me the error 'Cannot assign value of type 'CGAffineTransform' to type 'CGTransform3D'. I'm trying to figure this out but my attempts to fix this have been unfruitful.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out: Changed the problematic line to:

```
previewLayer?.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
```